# SQL Server column select query behaving strangely

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

When I do a `select *` over the table, the column `Qty` & `QtyPending` show a value of **6**. However explicitly selecting the column names shows different values. Can anyone shed some light as to why this behavior is occurring?

This is a legacy system and database used is SQL Server 2000. The column data types are `smallint`.

[image]

So I have explicitly updated `QtyPending` to 6 using an `Update` query. This column now shows correct value.

Also added locstockid to the query, column `Qty` still shows different values.

[image]

Comment: doesn't seem possible, really. Can you add the `LockStockId` to the second query to make sure of the results?

Comment: locstockid is added to both queries

Comment: you are using `SELECT QtyPending, Qty` in the second one, can you use `SELECT LockStockId, QtyPending, Qty` instead?

Comment: I think John means to try `SELECT LockStockID, QtyPending, Qty...` in the second query.

Comment: In the first query you have `152319` as the `LocStockID`. In the second query you have `153219` as the `LocStockID`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA AHAHA! Great catch :D

Comment: awesome, good catch @WEI_DBA

Comment: @John. Your LocStockID values are different. Even in the recent image you just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever I see in the image provided both the query have different LocStockId which means they can have different values

First : 
LocStockId = 152319

Second : 
LocStockId = 153219

I think you have mistyped.

Comment: ahh my bad!!! thanks man. I have been pulling my hair

Comment: Yes same, when I see it first, I was surprised to know such thing, but later when I tried to retype the queries, I found out the issue. This happens :)